# How to list installed apps from instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#restricted_features),

> The instant apps are restricted to discover the list of installed apps on the device, unless the
> installed apps have made themselves discoverable to instant apps.

There is also [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46411280/4417818) to make our app discoverable to instant apps.

But when we use `getPackageManager()`, the code crashes with the

> **error = Unfortunately, TheAppName instant app has stopped.**

Nothing is printed in Logcat. Following is printed on the Debug console,

```
02/10 22:57:27: Launching instantapp
Side loading instant app.
Side loading instant app.
Launching deeplink: https://myapp.mycompany.com/example.

$ adb shell setprop log.tag.AppIndexApi VERBOSE
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d https://myapp.mycompany.com/example -n "com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/.UrlHandler"
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner.test | com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner.test | com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner.test | com.mycompany.myapp.instantappscanner
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

Code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
}
```

Android Version : 6.0.1

**Update**

The reason for not printing Logs is [debugger was not attached to the App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44312415/4417818). The logs from adb console shows:

```
02-11 21:06:56.347: E/AndroidRuntime(18033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp.aninstantapp/com.mycompany.myapp.aninstantapp.feature.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Method class android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstalledApplications[int, int] not available to instant apps
```

[Full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/TheNilesh/c9909381dea07b8ef859267ddab2f557)

Stack trace prints that the call is not allowed from an instant app, but what if few apps made themselves [discoverable to instant apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46411280/4417818)? Rather than throwing exception method call should return a partial list of apps containing only apps which made themselves discoverable to instant apps?

---

### Short Question

Need help executing following code from an instant app.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

It throws exception,

```
SecurityException: IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstalledApplications[int, int] not available to instant apps
```

It should not throw an exception because one can have few apps which made themselves discoverable to instant apps, as supported by documentation (above).

Comment: What error message(s) do you see in logcat? Can you update your question to include those?

Comment: I'd recommend filing your issue with Google, then link to it back in here It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Put try/catches around each of your commands and see if you can print the exception to logs before the app goes down and please post the logs here.

Comment: @Nilesh, I cannot see the crash in my application, with O+ devices(Emulator Android Version 8.1 & 8.0.0). Crash visible with pre-O devices. Do you also observe the same behavior? If yes, I would recommend you file a bug to Google public portal.

Comment: @ManmeetP I tested with Android 6 and 7 devices. The App crashes there. Could you help me with how to file a bug at Google?

Comment: Refer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues and please share the required details. You should get the reply soon. Also please share the filed bug link here too.

Answer (score 2):

With Reference Instant App Documentation [3.15. Instant Apps](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#3_15_instant_apps)
device implementations MUST satisfy the following requirements:

- The target is explicitly exposed with ***`android:visibleToInstantApps`***

to make visible to *instant app* and it support from ***Android 8.0***

if we have to check ***`isInstantApp`*** from ***`installed app`***

***`isInstantApp(packageName)`*** will return a valid value(`false`) if the caller is able to see the instant app. The caller can see the instant app in the following scenarios:

- It is the instant app
- Is part of the system
- Holds the permission ***`ACCESS_INSTANT_APPS`***
- Is the system defined, default launcher holding
  the permission   ***`VIEW_INSTANT_APPS`***
- Is a regular app that the instant
  app has established a connection to an exposed component [*eg. bound
  to a service, started an activity, etc...*]

  [MoreInfo](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62368047)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is about listing installed apps(Not necessarily instant apps) from an instant app(my app) and the answer is about checking if an app is instant or not? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See Short Question Update

Comment: @Nilesh, i think as of now we don't have any other way to to do.

Comment: we can use `android:visibleToInstantApps`

Comment: We have to put `android:visibleToInstantApps` in manifest.xml of installed apps, that I did. but the problem is while listing those apps(discoverable apps) from an instant app.

Comment: @Nilesh, please can you check documentation carefully and take steps mention or can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267816/how-to-expose-component-from-installed-app-to-be-visible-to-instant-app. If it not resolve, i would recommend you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: @Nilesh, I hope your problem has been resolve or you have file a bug to google.please confirm.Thanks!