# How to connect to debug process when trying to debug android instant app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps, android-debug

My instant app is starting fine, but I am unable to debug it.
This is my Debug Log output:

```
    Waiting for application to start debug server
    Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapp.test | com.example.myapp
    Connecting to com.example.myapp
    Waiting for application to start debug server
    Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapp.test | com.example.myapp
    Connecting to com.example.myapp
    Waiting for application to start debug server
    Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapp.test | com.example.myapp
    Connecting to com.example.myapp
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session
```

I tried the accepted answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312415/android-instant-apps-how-to-debug-an-instant-app) related question but without luck.
I also tried the ***Attach Debugger to Android Process*** option, but it doesn't work.

Edit: I'm using both real device (Api 28) and emulator (Api 29) without success.

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you used android 5 or higher device because debugging is not available in versions before android 5.

Comment: thanks but see edited question, any other suggestion?

Comment: did you tried another example,check your mobile in developer mode try another PC if possible and make sure you use last android studio version also, check your USB connection.